# PHP reorder multidimensional array based on single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5068
            [Item] => 2737
            [Unit] => 15
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5067
            [Item] => 2737
            [Unit] => 13
        )

)
```

single dimensional array

```
Array (
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 15 
)
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5067
            [Item] => 2737
            [Unit] => 13
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5068
            [Item] => 2737
            [Unit] => 15
        )

)
```

It not necessary that single dimensional array must be in ASC/DESC order. I want to reorder multidimensional array according to single dimensional array based on unit value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
$multiDimArray = [
    0 => [
        'ID' => 5068,
        'Item' => 2737,
        'Unit' => 15
        ],
    1 => [
        'ID' => 5067,
        'Item' => 2737,
        'Unit' => 13
    ]
];

$singleDim = [
    11,13,15
];

usort($multiDimArray,function($a,$b){
    global $singleDim;
    return ($singleDim[0] >= $a['Unit']) ? -1 :1;
});

print_r($multiDimArray);
```

there's something in back of my head that tells me I'm missing something. But feel free to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values in the single array all map to a value in `Unit`, you could loop the single dimensional array and then loop the values in the multidimensional array.

In the inner loop use `in_array` to check if the value from the single dimensional array occurs in the multidimensional array. If it does, you could for example add it to a new array.

```
$result = [];

foreach ($singleDimension as $sm) {
    foreach ($multiDimensional as $md) {
        if (in_array($sm, $md)) {
            $result[] = $md;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vhaRR)